# Can piwik track the query string?

Tags: matomo

Piwik only seems to track the path part of the URL, not the query string. Is this a turn-onnable option? or perhaps I'm looking at the wrong report?

EDIT: I note that the log_action table includes the full URLs including query string, which gives me hope that the data may be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piwik displays query string also without making the report flat. You just have to reach the last level of URL (you can do it by clicking the row that has a plus icon near the URL).

Comment: hmmm, that didn't work at the time of asking the question. I now have auto archiving on, I wonder whether that is what makes it work... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Websites and check `Keep Page URL fragments when tracking Page URLs`.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's about [fragments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), not the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: Piwik by default displays whole query string. Which report are you looking at? Please check Visitor log and Actions -> Pages report. Please also see [Piwik demo](http://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday#/module=Actions&action=menuGetPageUrls&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Piwik does this by default (credit to @quba for pointing that out). But it's a little hidden:

At the bottom of the report there's a little cog icon. This itself may be hidden - if it's not there, look for a little down/up arrow, click that to reveal the cog icon.

Clicking the cog gives you a menu which allows you to select hierarchical or flat - flat view shows the query strings.

Documentation screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]