# piwik is not tracking the page with url parameter as search

Tags: javascript, php, matomo

I have installed piwik on my www folder by copying piwik into it.

Pasted the javascript tracking code on separate file lets say piwik.js and placed it in my local project www\myproj\js

My project contains php files,I have edited the file like below:

```
printf(<script src="js/piwik.js"></script>);
printf(</head>);
```

Placed the above statement in almost all the files.

Piwik dashboard tracking most of the files but some files it is not tracking.

I have noticed that the page with URL parameter as '**search**' is set with any value then piwik is not tracking.

localhost/myproj/sample.php?search=sthng

If search is empty it is working..localhost/myproj/sample.php?search=

Is that any reason behind this on piwik.

Please any one help me.

Comment: maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044732/can-piwik-track-the-query-string

Comment: @boroboris, my case is it is not tracking the full URL only if search query param has any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameter for site search in piwik settings using some keywords including search.

So, I have deleted the keyword and it is working properly.

The path is: Piwik dashboard->administration->websites and find query parameter there.

Comment: I've googled a bit and found this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: Thank you boroboris